# How to shorten this code by using a lookup table?

Tags: python, enums

I have the following code in a loop. Here pt is "parsed token" and
TT is `Token_Type` enum class. Can I shorten this code a bit?

```
if types[ind] == TT.MONTH_NAME:
    self.month = this_pt.value
elif types[ind] == TT.DAY_OF_WEEK:
    self.day_of_week = this_pt.value
elif types[ind] == TT.NTH:
    self.count = this_pt.value
elif types[ind] == TT.INT:
    self.day = this_pt.value
```

It would be nice to just look up the correct attribute in a table/dict and  save `this_pt.value` in it.

Comment: Can you show us TT or an abreviated version of it?

Answer (score 2):

One could create a mapping from the `TT` attributes to the instance attribute, and then use `setattr` using that information.

```
mapping = {
    TT.MONTH_NAME: "month",
    TT.DAY_OF_WEEK: "day_of_week",
    TT.NTH: "count",
    TT.INT: "day",
}

token_type = types[ind]
this_attr = mapping[token_type]
setattr(self, this_attr, this_pt.value)
```

If `token_type` is not guaranteed to be in the `mapping`, then you need to handle the case where the key is not present, perhaps with `try - except KeyError`

Comment: oh, I suspected setattr existed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to existing answer but a one-liner wrapped in an exception handler for the "none of the above" case.

```
types_map = {TT.MONTH: "month", TT.DAY_OF_WEEK:"day_of_week",
    TT.NTH: "count", TT.INT: "day"}

try:
    setattr(self, types_map[types[ind]], this_tp.value)
exept KeyError:
    pass
```

Comment: yep, this is what I was looking for. I did not know setattr existed. Thank you.